# Starting a Dwolla payment processor with Django: Do use an app or send POST, GET requests directly?

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, dwolla

This is my first project dealing with payment processors. I am using Dwolla in my Django project. I have never dealt with payment processors, and I want to know where should I start.

Do I need to use it just like the API's of Github, Twitter, etc, just by sending some POST or GET requests and getting the results from them. Or, is there any other way that I need to follow?

Comment: What are you using as ecommerce app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the workflow is basically the same as with any other payment web service. Just read the docs. A good starting point maybe [off-site gateway](https://www.dwolla.com/developers/offsitegateway).

There is also a [developer forum](https://getsatisfaction.com/dwolla).